# Get XML data - Jquery - Filter

Tags: jquery, xml, filter

I´m trying to use jquery filter function and parse XML but are having issues.
My XML looks like this:

```
<root>
    <data name="0121C395-AFCE-49C8-A163-55E24325D691" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Report an incident</value>
    </data>
    <data name="0121C395-AFCE-49C8-A163-55E24325D691_descr" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>In this service it's possible to report incidents.</value>
    </data>
    <data name="0121C395-AFCE-49C8-A163-55E24325D691_short" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Report Incident</value>
    </data>
</root>
```

And my Jquery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/servicemarket/ReachOut/Services.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            var dataVal = $(xml).find('data').filter(function(){
                return $('data', this).attr('name') == '0121C395-AFCE-49C8-A163-55E24325D691';
            });
            dataVal.each(function(index, data){
                console.log($(data).find('value').text());
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
        }
    });
});
```

My goal is to get node value based on incoming data attribute.
All help are much appreciated! :)
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be slightly modified:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
         url: "http://localhost/servicemarket/ReachOut/Services.xml"
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            var dataVal = $(xml).find('data').filter(function(){

                return $(this).attr('name') == '0121C395-AFCE-49C8-A163-55E24325D691';
            });
            //console.log(dataVal);
            dataVal.each(function(index, data){
                console.log($(data).find('value').text());
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
        }
    });
});
```

So, use `$(this)` to get current (found by find()) object. Your `$('data', this)` returned an empty object, because data doesn't contain another data tag inside (if i understand error correctly).